# Iterating through a Numpy array of plots and using element methods

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In trying to do some [small multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) stuff, I want to make a bunch of subplots with Matplotlib and toss in varying data to each.  `pyplot.subplots()`  gives me a `Figure` and Numpy array of `Axes`, but in trying to iterate over the axes, I am stumped on how to actually get at them.

I'm trying something akin to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
for ax in np.nditer(axs, flags=['refs_ok']):
    ax.plot([1,2],[3,4])
```

However, the type of `ax` in each iteration is not an `Axes`, but rather an `ndarray`, so attempting to plot fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

How can I loop over my axes?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this more simply:

```
for ax in axs.ravel():
    ax.plot(...)
```

Comment: `.ravel()` points to original array, while `.flat()` creates a copy. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930465/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-functions-in-numpy

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays have a [`.flat` attribute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat) that returns a 1-D iterator:

```
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.plot(...)
```

Another option is reshaping the array to a single dimension:

```
for ax in np.reshape(axs, -1):
    ax.plot(...)
```