# What is the difference between flatten and ravel functions in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, flatten, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)))
OUTPUT:
print(y.flatten())
[1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9]
print(y.ravel())
[1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9]
```

Both function return the same list.
Then what is the need of two different functions performing same job.

Comment: Ravel usually returns a view into the existing array (sometimes it returns a copy). Flatten returns a new array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between flatten and ravel in numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837312/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-in-numpy)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930465/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-functions-in-numpy/54313275#54313275) is a practical demonstration of subtle difference.

Comment: So can someone give an example when it is better to flatten an array and when to ravel it ?

Comment: Thank you for asking this, I had the same question.

Answer (score 541, accepted):

The current API is that:

- [`flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) always returns a copy.
- [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) returns a view of the original array whenever possible. This isn't visible in the printed output, but if you modify the array returned by ravel, it may modify the entries in the original array. If you modify the entries in an array returned from flatten this will never happen. ravel will often be faster since no memory is copied, but you have to be more careful about modifying the array it returns.
- [`reshape((-1,))`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) gets a view whenever the strides of the array allow it even if that means you don't always get a contiguous array.

Comment: Any idea why NumPy developers didn't stick to one function with some parameter copy=[True,False]?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Great question. I have no idea. The only reason I can think of is wanting to provide an easy analog to a similar matlab command. It doesn't appear to have any precedent in numarray or numeric.

Comment: Backcompat guarantees sometimes cause odd things like this to happen. For example: the numpy developers recently (in 1.10) added a previously implicit guarantee that ravel would return a contiguous array (a property that is very important when writing C extensions), so now the API is `a.flatten()` to get a copy for sure, `a.ravel()` to avoid most copies but still guarantee that the array returned is contiguous, and `a.reshape((-1,))` to really get a view whenever the strides of the array allow it even if that means you don't always get a contiguous array.

Comment: @IanH: Whats the difference between ravel and reshape then?

Comment: @Hossein IanH explained it: `ravel`guarantees a contiguous array, and so it is not guaranteed that it returns a view; `reshape` always returns a view, and so it is not guaranteed that it returns a contiguous array.

Comment: @iled: Thanks, then what's so important about being contiguous ? why would I want to care about that?

Comment: @Hossein That would be a whole new question. Very briefly, it is much faster to read and write to a contiguous memory space. There are several questions and answers on that here on SO ([nice example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059363/what-is-a-contiguous-memory-block)), feel free to open a new one if you have any further questions.

Comment: `reshape(-1)` is equivalent to `reshape((-1,))`

Comment: @diraria , we find that we can also pass order in "ravel" method. If it is 'C' which is default order then view of original array is returned. If is 'F' then it is a copied version of the array i.e. modification in this array is not reflected in actual array. (Not sure if this is a feature or bug :D)

Comment: Update: view of original array is not possible if order is 'F' in "ravel" function.https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12318

Comment: Why is it called `ravel`? What is the idea behind the name?

Comment: As these discussions reveal, Numpy is great, but not perfect.

Comment: "Unravel" means "investigate and solve or explain (something complicated or puzzling)". Maybe they really wanted the opposite of that, keeping people puzzled just like in this thread. :)

Answer (score 88):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28846614/1224158) a key difference is that:

- `flatten` is a method of an ndarray object and hence can only be called for true numpy arrays.
- `ravel` is a library-level function and hence can be called on any object that can successfully be parsed.

For example `ravel` will work on a list of ndarrays, while `flatten` is not available for that type of object.

@IanH also points out important differences with memory handling in his answer.

Comment: thx for that info about the ravel() working on lists of `ndarray`'s

Comment: Not only lists of arrays but also lists of lists :)

Answer (score 32):

Here is the correct namespace for the functions:

- [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)
- [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

Both functions return flattened 1D arrays pointing to the new memory structures.

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

r = numpy.ravel(a)
f = numpy.ndarray.flatten(a)  

print(id(a))
print(id(r))
print(id(f))

print(r)
print(f)

print("\nbase r:", r.base)
print("\nbase f:", f.base)

---returns---
140541099429760
140541099471056
140541099473216

[1 2 3 4]
[1 2 3 4]

base r: [[1 2]
 [3 4]]

base f: None
```

In the upper example:

- the memory locations of the results are different,
- the results look the same
- flatten would return a copy
- ravel would return a view.

How we check if something is a copy?
Using the `.base` attribute of the `ndarray`. If it's a view, the base will be the original array; if it is a copy, the base will be `None`.

---

Check if `a2` is copy of `a1`

```
import numpy
a1 = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
a2 = a1.copy()
id(a2.base), id(a1.base)
```

Out:

```
(140735713795296, 140735713795296)
```

Comment: `id(a1.base)` should be the same as `id(a2.base)`

Comment: a1.base and a2.base are both None, which is why the id of the base can/will be the same. But id(a1) and id(a2) are different due to copying. The bases will be different if a2 is a slice of a1 , in which case "a1.base is None" but "a2.base is a1"