# Differences between X.ravel() and X.reshape(s0*s1*s2) when number of axes known

Tags: numpy

Seeing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930580/3904031) I am wondering if the creation of a flattened view of X are essentially the same, as long as I know that the number of axes in X is 3:

```
A = X.ravel()

s0, s1, s2 = X.shape
B = X.reshape(s0*s1*s2)

C = X.reshape(-1)  # thanks to @hpaulj below
```

I'm not asking if A and B and C are the same.

I'm wondering if the particular use of `ravel` and `reshape` in this situation *are essentially the same, or if there are significant differences, advantages, or disadvantages to one or the other*, provided that you know the number of axes of X ahead of time.

The second method takes a few microseconds, but that does not seem to be size dependent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at their `__array_interface__` and do some timings.  The only difference that I can see is that `ravel` is faster.

`.flatten()` has a more significant difference - it returns a copy.

```
A.reshape(-1)
```

is a simpler way to use reshape.

You could study the respective docs, and see if there is something else.  I haven't explored what happens when you specify `order`.

I would use `ravel` if I just want it to be 1d.  I use `.reshape` most often to change a 1d (e.g. `arange()`) to nd.

e.g.

```
np.arange(10).reshape(2,5).ravel()
```

Or choose the one that makes your code most readable.

---

`reshape` and `ravel` are defined in `numpy` C code:

In https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0703f55f4db7a87c5a9e02d5165309994b9b13fd/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c

`PyArray_Ravel(PyArrayObject *arr, NPY_ORDER order)` requires nearly 100 lines of C code.  And it punts to `PyArray_Flatten` if the order changes.

In the same file, `reshape` punts to `newshape`.  That in turn returns a `view` is the shape doesn't actually change, tries `_attempt_nocopy_reshape`, and as last resort returns a `PyArray_NewCopy`.

Both make use of `PyArray_Newshape` and `PyArray_NewFromDescr` - depending on how shapes and order mix and match.

So identifying where reshape (to 1d) and ravel are different would require careful study.

---

Another way to do this ravel is to make a new array, with a new shape, but the same data buffer:

```
np.ndarray((24,),buffer=A.data)
```

It times the same as `reshape`.  Its `__array_interface__` is the same.  I don't recommend using this method, but it may clarify what is going on with these reshape/ravel functions.  They all make a new array, with new shape, but with share data (if possible).  Timing differences are the result of different sequences of function calls - in Python and C - not in different handling of the data.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, but I'm looking for a definitive answer. The extra microsecond(s) must mean something. However the `.reshape(-1)` is very helpful!

Comment: That requires finding them in the compiled code.  Clearly `ravel` takes a direct route, `reshape` a more general one.  Do I have to do the digging or will you?

Comment: You do not "have to do" anything of course! Answering questions is voluntary - no? But right now I can only read python. Maybe someone else might know?

Comment: We are talking about times where one level function redirection makes a big difference.  As long as the result is a `view`, there is no difference in how the 'data' is handled.

Comment: Wow! That is what I call a *definitive answer*!! I (and others) can actually learn a lot from your discussion. This is really helpful and I appreciate your time "going deep". Now I understand the significant time differences that do not scale with size. So far, I get the feeling that `ravel()` is the preferred for **flattened views** since it seems to be fastest.