# How to flatten zipped object containing nested arrays to a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy

I have a zipped object like this:

```
z = zip(a, b)
lst = list(z)

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[(0, array([[72, 65],
           [70, 71]], dtype=uint8)), 
(1, array([[ 71,  99],
           [190, 163]], dtype=uint8)), 
(2, array([[52, 59],
           [69, 72]], dtype=uint8)), etc...
```

I would like to flatten this list to the following:

```
[0, 72, 65, 70, 71, 1, 71, 99, 190, 163, 2, 52, 59 etc..]
```

I've tried doing this with

```
y = sum(w, ())
# or 
y = list(itertools.chain(*lst))
```

But the arrays are still there when I print.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The data is nested

Comment: Pay attention to the context in which you saw that advice. You can't just blindly apply it anywhere, you need to understand why it works in those cases.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - thx, I edited the title for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one of

- [`numpy.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) returns a contiguous flattened array.
- [`numpy.ndarray.flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat) returns a 1-D iterator over the array. (this is a `numpy.flatiter` instance)
- [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) that returns a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension.

Here is a MWE.

```
import numpy as np

lists = [(0, np.array([ [72,  65],
                        [70,  71]], dtype=np.uint8)), 
        (1, np.array([  [71,  99],
                        [190, 163]], dtype=np.uint8))]

l = list()
for idx, array in lists:
    l.append(idx)
    l.extend(np.ravel(array))   # returns a contiguous flattened array
    #l.extend(array.flat)       # return a 1-D iterator over the array.
    #l.extend(array.flatten())  # return a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension 

print(l)
# Output
[0, 72, 65, 70, 71, 1, 71, 99, 190, 163]
```

---

In speaking of the differences between `ravel` and `flatten`, excerpt from  [What is the difference between flatten and ravel functions in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930465/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-functions-in-numpy),

> The difference is that `flatten` always returns a copy and `ravel` returns
>   a view of the original array whenever possible. This isn't visible in
>   the printed output, but if you modify the array returned by `ravel`, it
>   may modify the entries in the original array. If you modify the
>   entries in an array returned from `flatten` this will never happen.
>   `ravel` will often be faster since no memory is copied, but you have to
>   be more careful about modifying the array it returns.

Comment: You don't need tolist, you don't actually need flatten either, you can `array.flat`, extend takes an iterable

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thx for pointing out this. I just edited my answer.

Comment: You can also use `.ravel` if you are going to extend, ravel does not always need to make a copy

Answer (score 3):

You data is nested so you would need chain to recursively flatten which chain does not do, what you can do is flatten the numpy arrays and add:

```
from itertools import chain

print list(chain.from_iterable(([a] + arr.flatten().tolist()) for a, arr in lst))
```

Or use `.flat` and an inner chain:

```
print list(chain.from_iterable(chain([a],  arr.flat) for a, arr in lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(chain([x], chain.from_iterable(y)) for x, y in z))
```

I'm using just `chain` for consistency but there are plenty of ways to flatten things, as @Padriac has shown.