# How to reshape numpy array of array into single row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

I would like to have it as

```
0
0
0
.
.
0
0
```

I know that we have to use the reshape function, but how to use it, is I am not able to figure out,

my attempt

```
np.reshape(new_arr, newshape=1)
```

Which gives an error

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)  isn't very friendly

Comment: `np.reshape(new_arr, newshape=-1)`.  The `-1` lets numpy calculate the required shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also have a look at [numpy.ndarray.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
a.flatten()

# array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The difference between `flatten` and `ravel` is that flatten will return a copy of the array whereas ravel will refence the original if possible. Thus, if you modify the array returned by ravel, it may also modify the entries in the original array.

It is usually safer to create a copy of the original array, although it will take more time since it has to allocate new memory to create it.

You can read more about the difference between these two options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930465/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-functions-in-numpy).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
np.reshape(new_arr, newshape=n*m)
```

where `n` and `m` are the number of rows and columns, respectively, of `new_arr`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ravel()` method :

```
In [1]: arr = np.zeros((2, 2))

In [2]: arr
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])

In [3]: arr.ravel()
Out[3]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reshape` function for same.

suppose we have an array

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

total 4 elements are there. We can convert using following command

```
a.reshape(4)

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```