# Numpy: Create a 1D array of numpy arrays when all arrays have the same length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to convert an existing 2D array to a 1D array of arrays. The only way I can find is to use something like:

```
my_2d_array = np.random.random((5, 3))
my_converted_array = np.zeros(len(my_2d_array), dtype='O')
for i, row in enumerate(my_converted_array):
    my_converted_array[i] = row
```

Is there a faster/cleaner method of doing this?

If the inner arrays have different shapes it is possible, for example:

```py
my_1d_array = np.array([
    np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.float),
    np.array([2], dtype=np.float)
], dtype='O')
assert my_array.shape == (2,)
```

But if the arrays are the same length numpy automatically makes it a 2D array:

```py
my_2d_array = np.array([
    np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.float),
    np.array([2, 3], dtype=np.float)
], dtype='O')
assert my_array.shape == (2, 2)
```

EDIT: To clarify for some answers, I can't use `flatten`, `reshape` or `ravel` as they would maintain the same number of elements. Instead I want to go from a a 2D array with shape `(N, M)` to a 1D array with shape `(N,)` of objects (1D arrays), which each have shape `(M,)`.

Comment: `new_array[:] = list(2d_array)` may be an alternative to your enumerate loop. In any case you do have to start with the right size object array.

Comment: Of course, very clever. Unfortunately I just benchmarked it and it takes ~2x longer than my for loop when the array is large.

Comment: Just to add, that is when the inner dimension is small, once it's larger than ~1000 the difference is more like 10%.

Comment: Your object array is practically a list.  Iterating on it is nearly as fast as iterating on a list, and faster than iterating on a 2d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method using `np.frompyfunc` that is a bit less typing than yours and comparable in speed - it seems roughly the same for small arrays but faster for large ones:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> def f_empty(a):
...     n = len(a)
...     b = np.empty((n,), dtype=object)
...     for i in range(n):
...         b[i] = a[i]
...     return b
... 
>>> def f_fpf(a):
...     n = len(a)
...     return np.frompyfunc(a.__getitem__, 1, 1)(np.arange(n))
... 
>>> def f_fpfl(a):
...     n = len(a)
...     return np.frompyfunc(list(a).__getitem__, 1, 1)(np.arange(n))
... 

>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=10000)

>>> a = np.random.random((10, 20))
>>> repeat('f_fpf(a)', **kwds)
[0.04216550011187792, 0.039600114803761244, 0.03954345406964421]
>>> repeat('f_fpfl(a)', **kwds)
[0.05635825078934431, 0.04677496198564768, 0.04691878380253911]
>>> repeat('f_empty(a)', **kwds)
[0.04288528114557266, 0.04144620103761554, 0.041292963083833456]

>>> a = np.random.random((100, 200))
>>> repeat('f_fpf(a)', **kwds)
[0.20513887284323573, 0.2026138547807932, 0.20201953873038292]
>>> repeat('f_fpfl(a)', **kwds)
[0.21277308696880937, 0.18629810912534595, 0.18749701930209994]
>>> repeat('f_empty(a)', **kwds)
[0.2321561980061233, 0.24220682680606842, 0.22897077212110162]

>>> a = np.random.random((1000, 2000))
>>> repeat('f_fpf(a)', **kwds)
[2.1829855730757117, 2.1375885657034814, 2.1347726942040026]
>>> repeat('f_fpfl(a)', **kwds)
[1.8276268909685314, 1.8227900266647339, 1.8233762909658253]
>>> repeat('f_empty(a)', **kwds)
[2.5640305397100747, 2.565472401212901, 2.4353492129594088]
```

Comment: A cleaver use of the fact that `frompyfunc` returns an object dtype array.  Usually that's a nuisance, here it's a useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you could call `ravel()` to convert any dimension arrays to `1d`.

```
my_converted_array = np.ravel(my_2d_array)
```

Learn more about `ravel()` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel).

Or you could simply use:

```
my_converted_array = my_2d_array.reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [136]: arr = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
In [137]: arr1 = np.empty(5, object)
```

Direct assignment doesn't work:

```
In [138]: arr1[:] = arr
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,3) into shape (5)
```

breaking the `arr` into a list of rows does

```
In [139]: arr1[:] = list(arr)
In [140]: arr1
Out[140]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]),
       array([ 9, 10, 11]), array([12, 13, 14])], dtype=object)
```

I'm not too surprised that your original is competitive in speed:

```
In [141]: for i,row in enumerate(arr):
     ...:     arr1[i] = row
```

`arr1` contains pointers just like the list

```
In [143]: list(arr)
Out[143]: 
[array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([3, 4, 5]),
 array([6, 7, 8]),
 array([ 9, 10, 11]),
 array([12, 13, 14])]
```

Operations on an object array nearly always require iteration and/or object referencing. Only things that run as fast as numeric array ones are those that don't do anything with the contents, like reshape and slice.

I found in other time tests that iteration on an object array is faster than iteration on the rows of an array, but still a bit slower than iteration on a list.

I have often made an array like this, but not in 'production' sizes.  Posters often want to go the other direction, converting an object array to 2d, so I have used this replicate their example.  Posters usually get an object array like this from something else, such as a Pandas dataframe, or some machine learning code that uses the object array for generality.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods like `ravel`, `flatten` and `reshape` to do the job. Learn the difference between them here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930465/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-functions-in-numpy).

Using `ravel` or `flatten` as

```
my_1d_array = my_2d_array.flatten() # Return (15,) dimension 
my_1d_array = my_2d_array.ravel() # Return (15,) dimension
```

Such `(15,)` type may inflict some inconsistency when performing some matrix operation and result inconsistent data result or program error.

So I prefer you to use `reshape` as follows:

```
my_1d_array = my_2d_array.reshape((-1,1)) # Returns (15,1) dimension
or,
my_1d_array = my_2d_array.reshape((1,-1)) # Returns (1,15) dimension
```

This way of reshaping into `(x, y)` ensures matrix operation will always result consistent data without any bugs.