# Extract nth value from 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a 3D array such as:

```
>>> arr = numpy.arange(36).reshape(3, 4, 3)
>>> arr
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]]])
```

How do I extract the *n*th value from each innermost row?

If I were to take the values for index 1, how can pull out the following?

```
array([[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [13, 16, 19, 22],
       [25, 28, 31, 34]])
```

or

```
array([ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***TLDR:***

```
arr[:,n]       # for 2d
arr[:,:,n]     # for 3d
arr[:,:,:,n]   # for 4d
arr[:,:,:,:,n] # for 5d
```

You can access using the last index:

```
import numpy

arr = numpy.arange(36).reshape(3, 4, 3)

print(arr[:, :, 1])
```

**Output**

```
[[ 1  4  7 10]
 [13 16 19 22]
 [25 28 31 34]]
```

Or,

```
print(arr[:, :, 1].flatten())
```

**Output**

```
[ 1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34]
```

You can find more information about numpy indexing [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by @MadPhysicist in the comments, you can use [ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) instead of flatten, the main difference is that flatten returns a copy and ravel returns a view. Also you can use an `arr[..., 1]` to access the last index, known as an ellipsis. From the documentation:

> Ellipsis expand to the number of : objects needed to make a selection
> tuple of the same length as x.ndim

**Further**

- [Ravel vs Flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930465/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-functions-in-numpy)
- [Ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do)

Comment: Thank you. I tried reading the numpy index page, but as I'm not familiar with numpy's advanced indexing, it's quite dense.

Comment: Ravel is preferable to flatten

Comment: You can also do `[..., 1]`

Answer (score -1):

To extract elements from such array you can do the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np   
>>> arr = np.arange(36).reshape(3, 4, 3)
>>> arr[:,:,1]
array([[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [13, 16, 19, 22],
       [25, 28, 31, 34]])
```

and if you want the flattened array you can do:

```
>>> arr.flatten()
array([ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34])
```

Comment: How is this any different from Daniel Mesejo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52572414/369450)?