# Create list of tuples of1D numpy array with every row of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array of values, and a 2D numpy array of values

```py
x = array([4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11])
y = array([0,1,2,3])
```

I want to create tuples of each row of y with the row in x

End result being

```py
array([(4,0),(5,1),(6,2),(7,3),(8,0),(9,1),(10,2),(11,3)])
```

Is there anyway to do this with numpy functions instead of for loops?

Comment: Do you expect to have array of tuples here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `len(y)` divides a size of `x`, you can merge a flatten view of `x` with an artificial padding with `np.tile` and then transpose result:

```
np.array([x.flatten(), np.tile(y, x.size//len(y))]).T
```

Note that `x.flatten()` is a synonym of `x.ravel()`.

Comment: Just a side note, `flatten()` is [not a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930465/what-is-the-difference-between-flatten-and-ravel-functions-in-numpy) of `ravel()`.

Comment: Thanks for a source

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
np.concatenate([list(zip(a,y)) for a in x ])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 4,  0],
       [ 5,  1],
       [ 6,  2],
       [ 7,  3],
       [ 8,  0],
       [ 9,  1],
       [10,  2],
       [11,  3]])
```

Or pure python:

```
list(zip(x.ravel(), np.tile(y,len(x))) )
```

Output:

```
[(4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 3), (8, 0), (9, 1), (10, 2), (11, 3)]
```

Comment: Isn't there a looping inside comprehension you did? Also, `np.repeat` works in a different manner than OP expects.

Comment: @mathfux thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer.